# Windows Server 2012: Does it allow the Win+U keyboard shortcut from lockscreen?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

in a few days I'll have a Windows Server 2012 server PC dumped into my lap. The employee who knew the passwords for it was fired. My first task assigned by my boss will be to log in as admin. I know that on normal Windows, you can create a new admin user from the lockscreen by replacing the exe that Win+U accesses from the lock screen with a copy of cmd.exe. What I don't know is if the same applies to Windows server. Does Windows server 2012 have lockscreen keyboard shortcuts? If so, does it have Win+U? Does Win+U access the same exe file (I think it was Utilman.exe) as on Windows 7 etc? If all these are true, I'm sure I should be able to hack my way in.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don’t you just enable the built-in Administrator account?

Comment: Because in the past that hasn't worked for me for various reasons, for example another PC in the same company had the built in admin "removed" somehow or permanently disabled, for security reasons, and I have no idea how they did it. But the process would still be the same for getting cmd open on the lockscreen. I still need to know the answers to my questions whether I use the built in admin or create a new admin.

Comment: The built-in Administrator can only be disable it cannot be removed or deleted.  You wouldn’t be keeping the account enabled only using it to reset the password to the account in question.

Comment: OK, assuming enabling the built in admin works, Either way i still need to know if you could use the same method to get to cmd from the lockscreen. Do you know? Thanks!

Comment: If it helps, Windows Server 2012 is based on Windows 8 not Windows 7, if the hack worked on Windows 8 then it will work on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: @Ramhound - Oh thank goodness, thank you so much for that info. I knew it was based on windows 8 but i didn't know whether it was close enough to the original that the same hack would work. The server hasn't made its way to me yet so I'm glad you were able to clarify that so I won't be clueless when I get it, since I'll have very little time to fix it once i get it. Thank you, you're the best!